# GoogleMap infowindow push onclick on a button

Tags: javascript, google-maps, typescript, ionic-framework

im using Googlemap JS API, i have some markers fetched from my Database and an infowindow foreach marker, on each infowindow i have a button wish pushes to another page with a certain variable, i tried to use ngZone, im not really familiar with it but i tried x), here's my code:

```
  // GET request to get data from database
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
  {

   var ouvrier=data[i].firstname+' '+data[i].lastname; //Getting data from db

   var Latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].lat,data[i].lon);
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: Latlng,
      map: this.map,
      labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 0),
      draggable:false,
      icon: { url : 'assets/imgs/worker.png',scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(70, 70)
    },

    });




    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: "Name: "+ouvrier+" <input type='button' id='clickableItem' value='consulter profile' >"
    }); 

    google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', () => {

      var clickableItem = document.getElementById('clickableItem');
      clickableItem.addEventListener('click', () => {
        this.zone.run( () => { //Im using ngZone
          console.log("wlidoz "+ data[i].idprof);
        this.navCtrl.push(ProfilPage, {
          profilId: data[i].idprof // PROBLEM HERE
      });

        });


      });
    });

  marker.addListener('click', event => {
    infowindow.open(this.map, marker);
    });

}
```

Everything is working fine, the map is loading..etc
But when i click on that button, nothing happens, i tried to console.log that `data[i].idprof` inside the ngZone but its undefined, but before the listener the console.log is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, i just declared a variable berfore the `google.maps.event.addLister` :

```
let idz=data[i].idprof;
    let that=this;
    google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', () => {

      var clickableItem = document.getElementById('clickableItem');
      clickableItem.addEventListener('click', () => {
        that.zone.run( () => {
        that.navCtrl.push(ProfilPage, {
          profilId: idz
      });

        });


      });
    });
```

If anyone has a better solution, i'll take it